# Find out on which line in text file is matching word

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

Is there any way to find out on which line of the text document is some word which is matching pattern for example with grep or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, its possible with the `-n` option of `grep`.

From [`man grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
-n, --line-number
              Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.
```

For example, if you have a file named `file.txt` having:

```
this is
foo test
and this is
bar test
```

Now the output of `grep -n "test" file.txt`:

```
$ grep -n "test" file.txt 
2:foo test
4:bar test
```

Here 2 and 4 indicates the line numbers where the pattern is found.

Comment: and is it possible just the number of line to be dispayed without the pattern?

Comment: @applenic: I am not aware of any `grep` option that can do what you want..but you can do `grep -n "test" file.txt | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: it doesn't need to be grep program, that was just an example

Comment: @applenic: Ok..so the above will do then :)

Answer (score 4):

The `grep` approach is the simplest but these will all print the line number of the line matching `pat`:

1. Perl

   ```
    perl -lne 'print $. if /pat/' file
   ```
2. awk

   ```
    awk '/pat/{print NR}' file
   ```
3. sed

   ```
    sed -n '/pat/=' file
   ```

Comment: hmmm - sed: 1: "/chrome-devtools/{=}": extra characters at the end of = command

Comment: I'm on bash in MacOS

Comment: @AlexanderMills ah, yes, the `{}` is unneeded and, apparently, a GNU `sed` thing. Try without them (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i=0; ++$i; put $i if /pat/;'
```

The Raku code above will print the line number of the line matching `pat`, one match-per-line. If you want all matches on one line, replace `put $i` with `print "$i "`.

By way of explanation, a lot of specialty variables in Perl have been omitted from Raku. Instead Raku enables `state` variables are initiated only once. That and a semicolon-separated 'C-like' syntax can be used for conditional line numbering in Raku. In the first statement above, a variable `$i` is declared with the `state` keyword, meaning it will be initialized exactly once. This `state` keyword works seamlessly with the traditional `-ne` Perl/Raku command line flags, such that `$i` can be incremented in the second statement with `++$i`, and matching values of `$i` can be `put` using the third statement.

Note, incremental (not conditional) line-numbering in Raku is accomplished by another method, which uses `$` anonymous state variables that can be incremented/decremented (e.g. `++$` or `$++` ). Thus numbering each instance of a matching pattern can be accomplished like so (using Raku's `=>` 'fat-arrow' hash constructor). Use `put` instead of `say` to get tab-separated output:

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i=0; ++$i; say (++$ => $i) if /4/;'
```

Sample Input (note first line is blank):

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
0123456
01234567
012345678
0123456789
```

Sample Output (final code above, 'ordinal-instance' `=>` 'line-number'. Use `put` instead of `say` to get tab-separated values):

```
1 => 6
2 => 7
3 => 8
4 => 9
5 => 10
6 => 11
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/state
https://raku.org